# HTML input type="file" show multiple file extension option

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload, input-type-file

I have a file upload on my page like below:

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" accept=".xls, .xlsx"/>
```

When open file dialog is opened, the option is like this
[image: Custom files]

What I want is like this. This is an example from Ms. Excel program, and I want the open dialog file selection to be like this or at least similar to this
[image: Multiple file options]

How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp here you can see all the attributes

Answer (score 0):

i think gives you all custom file options

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" accept="application/*"/>
```